# How long will the data be written into the new expanded DataNode of Apache IoTDB cluster?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I would like to ask, when expanding a DataNode in Apache IoTDB, will data be written to the expanded DataNode only when a new database is added? Or how long will the new data be written to the new DataNode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessary that only data from the new databases will be written into this new DataNode. The default partition should be one week in Apache IoTDB, so in the worst(longest) case, data will flow into your new DataNode after one week.